# Linker error when using v110_xp: "cannot open file ',5.01'"

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, linker-errors

I am building some Visual C++ DLL and EXE projects with Visual Studio 2012. When building with the default platform toolset *v110* the build is successful, but when building with the Windows XP compatible platform toolset *v110_xp* it fails with the following linker error in each project:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file ',5.01'

Note that if I change the platform from *Win32* to *x64* the errors change to:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file ',5.02'

This can be easily reproduced by creating a new EXE project from the "Empty Project" template in Visual Studio and adding some *.cpp file defining `int main() {return 6;}` . It will build successfully until you change the platform toolset from *v110* to *v110_xp*.

Why does this happen and how can I build these projects successfully with Windows XP compatibility?

Comment: MSBuild version 12.0 generates an explicit warning for this: "warning MSB8030: The linker switch "Minimum Required Version" requires "SubSystem" to be set.  Without "SubSystem", the "Minimum Required Version" would not be passed to linker and could prevent to the output binary from running on older Operating Systems."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the project properties, under *Linker* -> *System*, make sure that you **set the *SubSystem* property** (either to *Console* for console applications, or to *Windows* for DLLs and non-console applications).

If you use common property sheets (*.props) to set project properties across all of your projects, you can add something like this to make sure that *SubSystem* is assigned a valid value if the project doesn't specify one explicitly.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem Condition="'%(Link.SubSystem)'=='' Or '%(Link.SubSystem)'=='NotSet'">Windows</SubSystem>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

---

Why does this happen?

1. Choosing the *v110_xp* platform toolset automatically sets the *Minimum Required Version* linker setting to *5.01* or *5.02*, because this is the version of 32-bit and 64-bit Windows XP, respectively.
2. When the  the *Minimum Required Version* property is set, regardless of whether *SubSystem* is also set, Visual Studio tries to add both properties to the linker's command line arguments. This results in `,5.01` when *SubSystem* is not set (instead of the intended `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.01`), and the linker understands this as trying to specify a file named ",5.01".

The latter is a bug in Visual Studio (not directly related to *v110_xp*). When *Minimum Required Version* is set and *SubSystem* isn't, VS should either ignore *Minimum Required Version* or issue a warning, but it shouldn't send malformed arguments to the linker.